# conversion of array to string

Tags: c

```
`#include<reg51.h>
#include<string.h>
#include"_LCD_R8C.c"
unsigned char c[11];
void serial_int (void) interrupt 4
{
static unsigned char chr[11];
int i,j;
if (RI==1)      
{
    RI = 0;     
        TI = 0;     
    chr[11] = SBUF;       
        for(j=0;j<1;j++)
         {
       for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
        {
      c[i]=chr;
    }
       c[11]='\0';
     }
   }
}
```

> ```
> int main()
> {
> unsigned char a[2][11]={"$0016221826","$0123456789"};
> int i,j;
>     lcd_init();
>     lcd_clear();
>     SCON = 0x50;              
>     TMOD = 0x20;                
>     TH1  = 0xFD;                 
>     ET0  = 0;                     
>     TR1  = 1;                       
>     RI   = 1;                   
>     ES   = 1;                   
>     EA   = 1;                   
>     for(i=0;i<=1;i++)
> {
>   **j=strcmp(a,c);**
>     if(j==0)
>       {
>       lcd_printxy(1,1,"yes");
>       }
>     else
>       {
>       lcd_printxy(1,6,"no");
>       }
> }
> }`
> ```

the compiler is giving warning in line 55(BOLD): pointer to different objects. 
how about array to string conversion? is it correct? 
the received string should compare with the available array of strings..

Comment: The string `"$0016221826"` is not 11 characters, it's actually 12 characters (you forgot about the terminating `'\0'` character).

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg ok thank you, what about converting characters to string and comparing, if i take the characters as 12?

Comment: You don't need to co any conversions, an array degrades to a pointer, so you can use a `char` array everywhere a `char` pointer is expected. what makes an array a "string" is the type (`char`) and that it ends with zero.

Comment: I am not getting what you are telling, will you post the code plz? it will be helpful for me to understand

Comment: will you explain it clearly with an example

Answer (score 2):

Creating an array that contains a string, like

```
char foo[] = "bar";
```

it's actually the same as the following

```
char foo[] = { 'b', 'a', 'r', '\0' };
```

or the following

```
const char *foo = "bar";
```

This variable, `foo` can be used either as an array (i.e. the second letter is `foo[1]`) or as a pointer that can be passed to a function (like `strlen(foo)` will return 3).

So from the point of your program, a character array or a character pointer are equivalent, with the exception that you can't assign to a character array but you can assign to the pointer. So the following is okay:

```
char foo[] = "bar";
char *pfoo = foo;
```

But this is not okay:

```
const char *pfoo = "bar";
char foo[] = pfoo;    /* Error! */
```

There is also another thing that is different between character arrays and character pointers: Using the `sizeof` operator on a character array returns the number of characters in the array (including the terminating zero), but on a character pointer it returns the size of the pointer.

Example:

```
char foo[] = "foo";
const char *bar = "bar";

printf("sizeof(foo) = %lu\n", sizeof(foo));
printf("strlen(foo) = %lu\n", strlen(foo));
printf("sizeof(bar) = %lu\n", sizeof(bar));
printf("strlen(bar) = %lu\n", strlen(bar));
```

If you run the above code on a 64-bit machine (where pointers are eight bytes), it will print:

```
sizeof(foo) = 4
strlen(foo) = 3
sizeof(bar) = 8
strlen(bar) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

`a` is array of char pointers while `c` is character pointer. 
You would have to change your like to `j=strcmp(a[i],c);`

EDIT:

In your `serial_int` function, `chr` is array of chars so `c[i]=chr` is incorrect. I don't what your logic is, but syntactically it should be `c[i]=chr[i]`.

Also, you are not using `j` of parent loop, which indicates that you are doing same thing in each iteration of inner for loop.

Comment: k, in the loop i i am coping all the characters into the array c[i], in the j loop i am adding '\0' at the end and j loop is iterated for one time to add one null at the end of array to make it string.

Comment: if possible please post the exact code to conver array to string. otherwise modify my code and post it plz