# comparing array of strings

Tags: c

```
#include<reg51.h>
#include<string.h>
#include"_LCD_R8C.c"
unsigned char c[12];
unsigned char chr[11];
void serial_int (void) interrupt 4
{
  if (RI==1)      
  {
    chr[11] = SBUF;
    RI = 0;     
    TI = 0;     
  }
}

int main()
{
  unsigned char a[2][11]={"$0016221826","$0123456789"};
  int i,j;
  lcd_init();
  lcd_clear();
  SCON = 0x50;              
  TMOD = 0x20;                
  TH1  = 0xFD;                 
  ET0  = 0;                     
  TR1  = 1;                       
  RI   = 1;                   
  ES   = 1;                   
  EA   = 1;
  for(j=0;j<1;j++)
      {
       for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
       {
        c[i]=chr[i];
       }
     c[11]='\0';
     }                   
  for(i=0;i<=1;i++)
  {
    j=strcmp(a[i],c); /* !!! Here is the problem !!! */
    if(j==0)
     {
      lcd_printxy(1,1,"yes");
     }
    else
     {
      lcd_printxy(1,6,"no");
     }
 }
}
```

I am getting the display as "no", please let me know what is the problem?
the problem might be
1) the received array of characters are not converted to string, or
2) the received array of characters are converted to string but not able to compare with the available string.. 
   please go through the program

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210406/conversion-of-array-to-string

Comment: You don't seem to have incorporated the answers from your previous (possibly duplicate) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210406/conversion-of-array-to-string so you still have a lot of the same bugs as you did 2 hours ago ?

Answer (score 0):

One obvious bug for starters - change:

```
unsigned char a[2][11]={"$0016221826","$0123456789"};
```

to:

```
unsigned char a[2][12]={"$0016221826","$0123456789"};
```

(You need to allow room for the terminating `'\0'` in each string - I'm surprised your compiler didn't complain about this ?)

Also, this line in your interrupt handler is wrong:

```
chr[11] = SBUF;
```

Several problems with this - `char` only has storage for 11 chars, not 12, and you probably want to be accumulating characters from index 0 and then bumping the index, otherwise you're just overwriting the same character each time.

Looking at the rest of the code there are so many other problems that I think you may need to take a step back here and start with a simpler program - get that working first and then add to it in stages.

You might also want to get a decent introductory book on C and study it as there are lots of very basic mistakes in the code, so you might benefit from a better understanding of the language itself.

Answer (score 0):

You only assign a value to `chr[11]`, the rest of the array is uninitialized and will contain random data. You then copy this array containing random data to `c` (you could use e.g. `memcpy` here instead of looping yourself), and finally you compare the complete contents of `c` (which is random data) with one of the entries in `a`. So it's kind of natural that the result of that comparison will be that the strings are not equal.

**Edit:** A redesign of the program in the question

Your program has too many problems to be easily fixed, so I decided to try and rewrite it:

```
#include <reg51.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "_LCD_R8C.c"

#define INPUT_LENGTH 11
#define ACCEPTABLE_INPUT_COUNT 2

char input[INPUT_LENGTH];  /* The input from the serial port */
int  input_pos  = 0;       /* Current position to write in the input buffer */
int  input_done = 0;       /* 0 = not done yet, 1 = all input read */

void serial_int (void) interrupt 4
{
    if (!input_done && RI == 1)
    {
        /* Put the input at next position in the input buffer */
        /* Then increase the position */
        input[input_pos++] = SBUF;

        RI = 0;
        TI = 0;

        /* Check if we have received all input yet */
        if (input_pos >= INPUT_LENGTH)
            input_done = 1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    /* Array of data that this programs thinks is acceptable */
    /* +1 to the input length, to fit the terminating '\0' character */
    char acceptable_inputs[ACCEPTABLE_INPUT_COUNT][INPUT_LENGTH + 1] = {
        "$0016221826", "$0123456789"
    };

    iny acceptable_found = 0;  /* Acceptable input found? */

    /* Initialization */
    lcd_init();
    lcd_clear();
    SCON = 0x50;              
    TMOD = 0x20;                
    TH1  = 0xFD;                 
    ET0  = 0;                     
    TR1  = 1;                       
    RI   = 1;                   
    ES   = 1;                   
    EA   = 1;

    /* Wait until we have received all input */
    while (!input_done)
        ;  /* Do nothing */

    /* Check the received input for something we accept */
    for (int i = 0; i < ACCEPTABLE_INPUT_COUNT; i++)
    {
        if (memcmp(acceptable_inputs[i], input, INPUT_LENGTH) == 0)
        {
            /* Yes, the data received is acceptable */
            acceptable_found = 1;
            break;  /* Don't have to check any more */
        }
    }

    if (acceptable_found)
        lcd_printxy(1, 1, "Yes");
    else
        lcd_printxy(1, 1, "No");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am very sorry for that, I am looping here because, the data  which i am receiving through RS232  have series of characters, in order to compare the received data with the other available string i am converting  it to string using for loop, can **memcpy** to make it string?

Comment: @pradeep As long as the array contains normal characters, and is terminated by a zero, it's a a string. You could use e.g. `memcpy(c, chr, 11); c[11] = '\0';` instead of the strange loop.

Comment: in the previous example what you have explained is by taking the string directly i.e char foo[] = "bar"; but think that bar is now character, char foo[] = bar; this bar i want to make it string....

Comment: @pradeep I added a rewritten version of your program. In it a don't handle the input as strings _at all_. I also put each new byte received from the serial port in a new position in the input array. There are also other changes. It is of course untested (I don't have whatever hardware/software you have), but I think it _should_ work.

Comment: thanks a lot, but the keil compiler  was showing some errors     1)char acceptable_inputs[ACCEPTABLE_INPUT_COUNT][] = {
        "$0016221826", "$0123456789" error is unknown array size                so i have changed it to characceptable_inputs[ACCEPTABLE_INPUT_COUNT][INPUT_LENGTH]={
  "$0016221826", "$0123456789"

Comment: some of the doughts                                                         1)You let the ISR pick up 12 characters. Are you sure the 12th character of input[] would match the 12th character of your reference keys?   2)ISR don't do anything in case the input buffer already is filled.           3) How do you get your ISR to synchronize the input, in case you miss one character or there is one character too much? Consider what happens if you disconnect/reconnect the serial cable while data is transmitting? Wouldn't it be good to consider the dollar or '\r' or '\n' as synchronization characters?

Comment: @pradeep Updated to make input 11 character, to match the strings, and also updated the `acceptable_inputs` array. I don't know about the details of your hardware or your compiler, but the interrupt routine will not read to much, as for the problem with disconnected wire there won't be a problem as long as the sender stops sending when there is no connection. For safe protocol you need to check e.g. carrier signal status _and_ invent a better protocol (with acks and maybe sequence numbering).

Comment: what do you mean by this sentence "but the interrupt routine will not read to much"? please can you explain it ....

Comment: @When the interrupt routine has read `INPUT_LENGTH` characters, it will set a flag (`input_done`), if that flag is set then the interrupt routine will not read anything more, ever. However, you might want to change so that it resets the interrupt anyway, and maybe read but discard whatever data is read when the flag is set.

Comment: I am not getting the exact no which i am receiving instead i am getting 255